# How to carry the data from page to another page

Tags: php, codeigniter

How to carry the data from this page to another page? Example I have this view page called `create.php` and i have some value inserted over here

```
<div class="form-group">
     <label>Body</label>
     <textarea class="form-control" name="body" placeholder="Ask Somenthing..."></textarea>
</div>
```

now i want the value that I inserted to be use to another view page(`suggestion.php`) without inserting it in the database.

Ps. `suggestion.php` is the one that can insert the data from `create.php` in the database.

Is it possible? Can anyone show me the way to do it?

Comment: can you include the name of your method in a controller?

Answer (score 0):

To carry data between pages, you could rewrite your existing HTML so that the text area is within a form.

```
<!-- create.php -->
<form method='post' action='suggestion.php'>

    <label for='body'>Body</label>

    <textarea class='form-control' name='body'></textarea>

    <input type='submit' name='submit'>

</form>
```

Then, when your form is submitted, the action parameter of the form is triggered - sending you to `suggestion.php`. Within the next file you could do something like this to retrieve the information that was put into the textarea.

```
// suggestion.php
if (isset($_POST['body'])) {

    // corresponds to the 'name' attribute of the inputs
    echo $_POST['body'];

}
```

The above will echo onto the `suggestion.php` page whatever was put into the text area. The information input on the first page is now available on the second, so you can use it as you wish - you can very easily use this variable now to insert into your database.